# How to parse url with DOMparser using getNamedItem

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, domparser

I am trying to grab URL, with `DOMparser` but stuck at `getNamedItem`
How to solve this problem? What I am missing here? I welcome for any idea!

```
$url = 'https://www.31sumai.com/search/area/kansai/result/?area=16,17,18';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
$DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
$mainlink = null;
$allPTags = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($allPTags as $ptag) {
     $class = $ptag->attributes->getNamedItem("class");
     if ($class && $class->nodeValue == 'c-name') {
         $main = $ptag->attributes->getNamedItem("href");
         if ($main) {
             $mainlink = $main->nodeValue;
          }
     }
}

var_dump($mainlink);
```

It s returning null but already checked the website, there is a URL in that tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $url = 'https://lions-mansion.jp/area/kansai/';
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
    $DOMParser->loadHTML($html);
    $mainlink = null;
    $allPTags = $DOMParser->getElementsByTagName('p');
    foreach ($allPTags as $ptag) {
        $class = $ptag->attributes->getNamedItem("class");
        if ($class && $class->nodeValue == 'areapageDetailList_item_btn_hp') {
            $links = $ptag->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                $hrefAttr = $link->attributes->getNamedItem("href");
                if ($hrefAttr) {
                    $mainlink = $hrefAttr->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo $mainlink;
```

Comment: it's likely impossible, I changed the link and used your script. But again NULL returning. I update the question codes, you could check it yourself on that website too..

Comment: If you trying to find link inside p tag with class 'areapageDetailList_item_btn_hp' you should find 'a' element inside $ptag and then get href from that element $a->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue;

Comment: Updated answer. Now it search link inside p tag with class 'areapageDetailList_item_btn_hp'